# Assets 2 MSM Cannot Upload or view images

Tags: multi-site-manager, pixelandtonic, assets

I have a multisite installation of EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.0.3.

The issue I am running into is that if I log into Site 1 at url.com/admin.php and navigate to the Assets module I can see all my Site 1 images. If I switch to Site 2 using the top right navigation none of the images for Site 2 load. I have verified all the config/file upload settings and everything is correct.

I also cannot index anything from within Site 2, only within Site 1.

I can log into Site 2 and site2url.com/admin.php and the images will show up.

This seems to defeate the MSM system a bit because our client has to log into both site admin sections in order to view files.

From my understanding this ins't correct and I should be able to see the files on both sites by logging into Site 1.

is this a bug or am I missing a config somewhere?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

Kevin - first thing, please update Assets to 2.0.5.  Second, can you try adding this to your /system/expressionengine/config/config.php please?

$config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';

Please let me know if either or both of those get you up and running!

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Unlike the OP, I *can* see all my Assets files in the Control Panel under the Site1 domain. I can't do much of anything in the second site's CP because the master config sets its base URL to be the second site's base URL. SO, I'm fine as far as the CP, but my Assets tags in my templates have no output. I can copy and paste to a template in Site1 and they work fine, in Site2, no output. I have that line in my config.php.

Comment: The channel I'm using is a Site1 channel, in a Site2 template. All other channel fields are outputting properly.

Comment: Mark, I'm thinking that a separate post, where you can include your versions and template code, would be the best way to follow this through.  Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks, Lisa! I posted at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/8942/293 and did manage to get things working (my own answer). You may want to take a look at what it took and there's 1 remaining snag that's not as important for me.